# Extract words contains only alpanumeric from a given string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Can someone please tell me how can I extract the "model name" from the below product names. As an example all I need is, extract "SGS45A08GB" from "Bosch SGS45A08GB Silver Dishwasher". Seems like I have to create Regex to identify words which has Alphanumric values for given string. Can someone give me some c# example to get this done.

Some example strings with model names:

```
Bosch SGS45A08GB Silver Dishwasher
        Bosch Avantixx SGS45A02GB Dishwasher, White
        Bosch SMS53E12GB White Dishwasher
        Bosch SGS45A08GB Dishwashers
        BOSCH SGI45E15E Full-size Semi-Integrated Dishwasher
        Bosch SKS60E02GB Compact Dishwasher, White
        BOSCH SRV43M03GB Slimline Integrated Dishwasher
        BOSCH Classixx SGS45C12GB Full-size Dishwasher - White
        BOSCH SGS45A02GB Dishwashers
        Bosch 18V Cordless Drill Driver
        Bosch PSB 18V Li-Ion Hammer Drill
        Bosch SGS45A08GB Dishwasher
        Bosch SGS45A08 12Place Full Size Dishwasher in Silver
```

**EDIT:** Adding more product names

```
    Hitachi DH24DVC 4kg Cordless SDS Plus Hammer Drill 24V
    DeWalt DW965K 12V Angled Drill Driver
    Grove Modern Bathroom Suite with Acrylic Bath
    Bosch GBH24V 3.2kg SDS Plus Drill 24V
    Makita LS0714/1 190mm Sliding Compound Mitre Saw 110V
    Grove Modern Bathroom Suite with Steel Bath
    Swann All-in-One Monitoring & Recording Kit with LCD
    Makita BHR202RFE LXT 3.2kg SDS+ Rotary Hammer Drill 18V
    DeWalt DW625EK-GB 2000W Router 240V
    Trade Triple-Extension Ladder ELT340
    Makita 6391DWPE3 18V Drill Driver
    Erbauer ERF298MSW 165mm Sliding Compound Mitre Saw 24V
```

Comment: `Bosch 18V Cordless Drill Driver` looks like it's missing a part number.

Comment: You might need to refine your criteria for model name extraction. For example, "18V" in "Bosch 18V Cordless Drill Driver" is alphanumeric but is not a model name. It is also possible for model names to not have any numbers.

Comment: Do all of the line items actually contain a model name? If so then do they all start with "S"?

Comment: @Kurtnell
No actually it will also have models from another brands. But if I need the model names from these names for now this is the only way I can think of for now. Here are some examples. =====


Erbauer ERF298MSW 165mm Sliding Compound Mitre Saw 24V
Makita P-71831 Tape Measure Holder
Hitachi DH24DVC 4kg Cordless SDS Plus Hammer Drill 24V

Comment: Will there be a know number of Upper case chars before the alphanumeric chars?

Comment: @Justin -- Yeah some product does have these kind of sizes too. for example it can be "Brand+Model+20Cm foo bar", So I probably need to have a mechanism to ignore these types of words from the string. I have already created a library of these types of Noice words, where I will be able to remove them accordingly. But I can't expect 100% accuracy though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define "alphanumeric" as a string that contains both ASCII uppercase letters and numbers, and if you assume a minimum length for a model name (let's say 8 characters), then you can match all the names from your example using

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"\b             # word boundary
    (?=[A-Z]*[0-9])  # assert presence of at least one ASCII digit
    (?=[0-9]*[A-Z])  # assert presence of at least one ASCII letter
    [0-9A-Z]{8,}     # match at least 8 characters
    \b               # until a word boundary", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResults.Success) {
    // matched text: matchResults.Value
    // match start: matchResults.Index
    // match length: matchResults.Length
    matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
}
```

I think that uppercase ASCII letters and digits is a reasonable assumption for model names, but if that's not correct, you need to show us more examples.

**EDIT:**
 With your new examples, the following regex works, but the constraints are getting looser and looser, and you'll probably never find a regex that reliably matches all possible model names.

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"\b             # word boundary
    (?=\S*[0-9])   # assert presence of at least one ASCII digit
    (?=\S*[A-Z])   # assert presence of at least one ASCII letter
    [0-9A-Z/-]{6,} # match at least 6 characters
    \b             # until a word boundary", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Comment: Hi Tim, really appreciate your help. Sorry for not mentioning this on first place. Yeah the model names that I need to extract not always in the same identical format. In most cases all most all model names has Letters+Digits. That's what I'm thinking of exatracting those words. I'm NOT expecting 100% accuracy becuase this is not the best approch. But this is best so far. I'll show you more examples. (Already hit the char limit for this comment )

Comment: I have added more possible product names. Hope my queustion is much clearer now.

Comment: Hi Tim, I think this is the best option and I'm happy to go ahead with this Regex pattern. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well dude this is the best that I could do. Note some of the items don't have any model number:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication3 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string _data = @"Bosch SGS45A08GB Silver Dishwasher
            Bosch Avantixx SGS45A02GB Dishwasher, White
            Bosch SMS53E12GB White Dishwasher
            Bosch SGS45A08GB Dishwashers
            BOSCH SGI45E15E Full-size Semi-Integrated Dishwasher
            Bosch SKS60E02GB Compact Dishwasher, White
            BOSCH SRV43M03GB Slimline Integrated Dishwasher
            BOSCH Classixx SGS45C12GB Full-size Dishwasher - White
            BOSCH SGS45A02GB DishwashersBosch 18V Cordless Drill Driver
            Bosch PSB 18V Li-Ion Hammer Drill
            Bosch SGS45A08GB Dishwasher
            Bosch SGS45A08 12Place Full Size Dishwasher in Silver";

            Regex _expression = new Regex(@"\p{Lu}{3}\d+\w+\s+");
            foreach (Match _match in _expression.Matches(_data)) {
                Console.WriteLine(_match.Value);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi kurtnelle, it works too, but I'm not good in Regex to understand it clearly. If possible please let me know how the pattern works. cheers!

Comment: Ok so the \p{Lu} means upper case chars {3} means exactly 3. \d+ is 1 or more decimals. \w+ is one or more alphanumeric case insensitive chars and \s+ is one or more white spaces.

Comment: Additionally {2,3} means between 2 and 3 (instead of exactly). You should try getting the regular expression tool Expresso, as it will help you learn how to use regular expressions (it was still free last time I checked)

Comment: Thanks Kurtnelle, I'll check that out.